# Waiting for a Java keypress

Tags: java

The application I am wishing to write is quite large, but requires being run as a service.  I plan on using FireDaemon to convert it and run it as a service, but need to have it do nothing until a specific key is pushed.

I tried using `DataInputStream` and a do/while loop which would wait for a key press, something like this:

```
do {
   char keyPressed = input.readChar();
} while (keyPushed != null);

System.out.println("You pushed: " + keyPushed);
```

There isn't all that much information on this simple topic and I find that odd.  In Basic we used to use inkey$ which would wait for a key, Java has to have something similar, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Any help would be nice.

Thanks.
Bob Grant,
Pennsylvania

Comment: readChar is blocking call. DO you want to have it or want to listen to key presses on a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (System.in.available() > 0)
    System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are wanting your application to run in the background on the Windows OS until a specific key combination is entered - e.g. a hot key. You will not be able to do this in Java alone, the sdk does not provide such an interface. You will need to write a helper app in C and use JNI as a bridge.

This article should help you out a bit - [Global hotkeys for Java applications under Windows OS](http://biletnikov-dev.blogspot.com/2009/09/global-hotkeys-for-java-applications_25.html)